# Double-JOIN in web2py. How to apply this SQL in web2py?

Tags: database, join, web2py

In my image-labeling app I want to display a list of labels assigned to an image along with lable-type and user information, who assigned this lable.
The main table is imageLabel. The tables auth_user and labelType contain additional information to the label.

Could you help me converting this SQL-statement to web2py:

```
SELECT labelType.name, imageLabel.labelValue, auth_user.first_name, auth_user.last_name  from imageLabel
LEFT JOIN labelType 
ON imageLabel.labelId = labelType.id
LEFT JOIN auth_user
ON imageLabel.userId = auth_user.id
WHERE imageLabel.imageId = 581
ORDER BY labelType.name
```

The data model is like this:

```
db.define_table('labelType',
    Field('name','string'),
)
db.define_table('imageLabel',
    Field('imageId','string'),
    Field('labelId','integer'),
    Field('userId','integer'), 
    Field('labelValue','text'),
)
db.define_table('image',
    Field('imageId','string')
)
# + built-in auth tables
```

My attempt was:

```
labels = db((db.imageLabel.id == db.labelType.id) ).select( 
        db.imageLabel.labelValue, db.labelType.name, db.auth_user.first_name, db.auth_user.last_name, db.imageLabel.labelTimeStamp, 
        left=db.auth_user.on(db.imageLabel.userId==db.auth_user.id)
        )
```

Which abviously doesn't work as there is no WHERE imageLabel.imageId = 581 part in the code. And I can't figure out how to use WHERE along with 2 "JOINS" in web2py :-(

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

**EDIT: SOLUTION After reading answer from Anthony:**

```
labels = db(
    db.imageLabel.imageId == img.id
).select(
    db.imageLabel.labelValue,
    db.labelType.name,
    db.auth_user.first_name,
    db.auth_user.last_name,
    db.imageLabel.labelTimeStamp,
    left=[
        db.labelType.on(db.imageLabel.labelId == db.labelType.id),
        db.auth_user.on(db.imageLabel.userId==db.auth_user.id)
    ],
    orderby=~db.labelType.name
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, a select looks like `db(query).select(...)`. The `query` part of that represents the `WHERE` clauses. If you have multiple `WHERE` clauses, you just use the `&` operator:

```
db((condition 1) & (condition 2) & ...)
```

As for [left joins](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#Left-outer-join), the `left` argument of the `.select()` method can be a list if you need to specify multiple left joins:

```
left=[db.auth_user.on(db.imageLabel.userId==db.auth_user.id),
      db.labelType.on(db.imageLabel.labelId==db.labelType.id)]
```

However, it's not clear that you really want left joins here -- you might just want inner joins (which can be specified using the `join` argument to the `.select()` method, or more simply as conditions in the query):

```
db((db.imageLabel.labelId == db.labelType.id) &  # joins imageLabel and labelType
   (db.imageLabel.userId == db.auth_user.id) &  # joins imageLabel and auth_user
   (db.imageLabel.imageId == 581))\
  .select(db.imageLabel.labelValue, db.labelType.name, db.auth_user.first_name,
          db.auth_user.last_name, db.imageLabel.labelTimeStamp)
```

Also, you should probably specify the three "Id" fields as reference type fields:

```
db.define_table('imageLabel',
    Field('imageId', 'reference image'),
    Field('labelId', 'reference labelType'),
    Field('userId', 'reference auth_user'),
    Field('labelValue', 'text'),
)
```

Finally, why do you need an imageId string field? The db.image table will already have an auto-incrementing integer "id" field to serve as a primary key for the table and uniquely identify each image.

Comment: +1: Thank you for valuable suggestions! Using a list as left-value was the key! Now it works and I've added the solution to my question. Especially, many thanks for good explanation for db().select(). I'didn't get it from online-book. Concerning [image.imageId], the name is indeed misleading. Actually this field stores a 32-char long hash-value of the image in order to prevent importing existing images. It is not primary key of the image-table (However it could be, as these values are also unique)

Comment: Oh, now I see, there was another error in my schema. You've meant imageLabel.imageId. It was nonsense indeed. Thanks again!